# What's wrong with this bash prompt?

Tags: bash, git, prompt, command-line-interface

I use the following entry in `~/.bashrc` file to colorize the prompt and display current branch of git repository:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\[\u@\h\]\[\e[m\] \[\w\]\[\e[1;1m\]\[$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\] \[\e[1;1m\]\[$\] \[\e[m\]'
```

This works almost fine, except when I use bash history (up arrow key few times), the command line becomes 'outdented' (just the first characters of the prompt remains untouched), and the visible is:

```
usemmand
```

when my username is `user` and the command is `command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct version:

```
COLOR1="\[\e[1;32m\]"
COLOR2='\[\e[1;1m\]'
COLOR3='\[\e[m\]'
GIT_STATUS=$(__git_ps1 " %s")
PROMPT_CHAR="$"

PROMPT="${COLOR1}\u@\h${COLOR3} \w${COLOR2}${GIT_STATUS} ${COLOR2}${PROMPT_CHAR} ${COLOR3}"
PS1="$PROMPT"
export PS1
```

Answer (score 4):

`\[` and `\]` should only be used around parts of the command prompt that *do not* advance the cursor, despite having actual text. if `__git_ps1` produces any visible output then this will desynchronize your command line.

Comment: Just to clarify, it should not be around `\u@\h`, `\w` or `$` either.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone working with this issue, here is the example that worked for me:

**BEFORE:**

```
export PS1="\033[0;33m[\u@\h]\033[1m\e[m \w \033[36m[>>]\033[0m\e[m "
```

**AFTER:**

```
export PS1='\[\033[0;34m\][\u@\h]\[\033[1m\e[m\] \w \[\033[35m\][>>]\[\033[0m\e[m\] '
```

Notes all the `'\\[\\]'` around the colors.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the single quotes and the double quotes, as it relates to this prompt?